# Can someone explain what this theorem means?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, proof-explanation, education

here is the theorem

**"If a polynomial with real coefficients in one unknown has all of
its roots being real number, then the number of positive roots, counted with
their multiplicity, equals the number of variations of signs among the ordered
sequence of his coefficients"**

Unforunately i am not understand what the theorems trying to say , can someone explain what this therem trying to say and give some examples?

Comment: Please state where this theorem is from, in particular what name it has if you know that. FYI, it's very similar to the [Positive roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs#Positive_roots) part of the Descartes' rule of signs.

Comment: I think in place of "equals" you should be saying "is at most equal to". Google [Descartes rule of signs](https://www.google.com/search?q=descartes+rule+of+signs).

Comment: I don't know the theorem says " equals "

Comment: Is it terminology that confuses you (if so, which terms?), or the overall phrasing? ... Removing clutter, understanding that we're talking about a polynomial w/real coeffs in the "standard" order $a_0+a_1 x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_nx^n$ (or the reverse), the statement is *"The # of positive roots is [at most] the # of sign changes in the sequence $a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$."* In tallying "# of roots", a multiple root counts ... well ... *multiply*: a double-root counts twice, a triple-root counts thrice, etc. Also, "# of sign changes" counts flips from $+$ to $-$ or back, ignoring $0$s. Does that help?

Comment: Shall we change "equals" to be " at most"?

Comment: Descartes says "at most". ... Actually, the complete Rule of Signs states that *"The number of positive roots matches the number of sign changes, **minus** some even number (which might be zero)."* Saying *"The # of positive roots is at most the # of sign changes"* makes for a weaker statement.

Comment: But i think that Theorems , does not matter wheter there exist  it is imaginary roots or not , but this theorem requires all roots must be real so this theorem might be true (i.e  it is true if we write "equal")

Comment: @BREYSKS: Ah, you're right. I glossed over that in my reading; sorry. ... In the Rule of Signs, the subtracted even number from the number of sign changes accounts for the possibility of imaginary roots (which occur in conjugate pairs due to the coefficients being real). If we stipulate that *all* roots are real, then we subtract nothing: the number of positive roots is the number of sign changes. (That said, it's a bit unusual in practice to know *a priori* that all roots will be real.)

Comment: Do you have a recommended sources to read the Descartes rule proof?.Seems like i cant find the satisfying proof on internet , they somehow gives alot of claim but they didnt prove it

Comment: @BREYSKS: Proof can be annoyingly fiddly. Stewart Levin's ["Descartes' Rule of Signs - How hard can it be?" (PDF link via stanford.edu)](http://sepwww.stanford.edu/data/media/public/oldsep/stew_save/descartes.pdf) spends 8 pages on a proof, suggesting that the result isn't exactly trivial. On the other hand, [Cut-the-Knot](https://cut-the-knot.org/fta/ROS2.shtml) has a one-(extra-long-)page proof. Benisimhoun's ["Historical account and ultra-simple proofs ..." (via arXiv.org)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.6664) seems promising, but I haven't read it. You can also search Math.SE.